# React Native Stacknavigation Custom back button on defaultNavigationOptions

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I currently have a `static navigationOptions` on every single page where I override the backbutton. I'm trying to change this so it uses `defaultNavigationOptions` instead. How do I access the back functionality of the navigationstack from the navigation file itself?

Current code:

```
const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    // screens
},
{
    headerLeft: (
        <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => /* navigate back */}
        style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginLeft: 10 }}
        >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} color="#ffffff" />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )
    }
  }
);

export const LoginNavigation = createAppContainer(LoginNavigator);
```

This gets imported into the main app, may that help.